# What does 'a nasty bit of' mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> "Is he always that nervous?" 
>        "Oh,
>   yeah. Poor bloke. Brilliant mind. He was fine while he was studyin'
>   outta books but then he took a year off ter get some firsthand
>   experience. . . . They say he met vampires in the Black Forest, and
>   there was **a nasty bit o'** trouble with a hag –– never been the same
>   since. Scared of the students, scared of his own subject now, where's
>   me umbrella?" 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

‘Nasty’ has the meaning of [‘very serious’](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/nasty), ‘bit’ [‘a small amount’ or ‘a large amount’](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/bit). Then what does ‘a nasty bit of’ mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would interpret it as a combination of the first two of your suggestions: in other words, the character is describing a short-lived but very serious troubling episode with a hag.

One might use the same word when describing, say, a loud argument between neighbors:

> Those two got into a **nasty** spat a couple of weeks ago. I don't think they've spoken to each other since.